# Validação de dados de formulário no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataannotations

Há alguma maneira mais rápida e simples de validar os dados de um formulário no ASP.NET? de forma que eu não tenha que ficar fazendo tantos tratamentos como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Attempt(string email, string password, Entities db)
{
    ViewBag.email = email;

    if (email == null || password == null || password.Length < 5)
    {
        TempData.Add("error", "E-mail ou senha inválidos.");
        return RedirectToRoute("Admin.Login");
    }

    var admin = db.admins.Where(p => p.email == email).FirstOrDefault();

    if (admin == null)
    {
        TempData.Add("error", "E-mail ou senha inválidos.");
        return RedirectToRoute("Admin.Login");
    }

    if(BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(password, admin.password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
    }

    TempData.Add("error", "E-mail ou senha inválidos.");
    return RedirectToRoute("Admin.Login");
}
```

Procuro alguma biblioteca de validação mais prática, como esta do laravel, em php, por exemplo:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email'    => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
    'password' => 'required|min:5'
], [
    'required'  => trans('errors.required'),
    'min'       => trans('errors.min'),
    'email'     => trans('errors.email'),
    'exists'    => trans('notifications.login_failed'),
], [
    'email'     => trans('all.email'),
    'password'  => trans('all.password'),
]);
```

Que já retorna para a View todos os erros do Validator, caso haja:

```
if($validator->fails())
    return redirect()->route('login', $panel->handle)
        ->withInput($request->except('password'))->withErrors($validator);
```

Comment: Jquery Validate já tentou?

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma validação Server Side mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde tem maneira mas simples de validação server side seria usando 
data annotation ele já tem algumas propriedades prontas mas querendo você pode customizar vou colocar um exemplo abaixo.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class EadCapituloModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Capitulo é Obrigatorio")]
    [Display(Name = "Capitulo")]
    public string Capitulo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo tempo é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Tempo")]
    public string Tempo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo curso é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "PlataformaId")]
    public int PlataformaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Nome do video obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Video")]
    public string Video { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo url é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "URL")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$", ErrorMessage = "Url não é válida")]
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

segue um site que contém algumas explicações sobre cada annotation:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx